# How to add an eventlistener to a button javascript

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

How can I add an eventlistener to my button? When the button is clicked the function speler1gooien has to run. When I run my example code below the function speler1gooien is fired on page load. What is the correct way to run my function only when clicked?

```
window.onload = function () {
            buttonSpeler1 = document.getElementById("buttonspeler1");
            buttonSpeler2 = document.getElementById("buttonspeler2");
            tafelp2.src = "images/rechts_" + aantalBekersP2 + ".png";
            resultaat = document.getElementById("resultaat");
            buttonSpeler1.addEventListener("click", speler1gooien());
        };

        var speler1gooien =  function() {
            // some code

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis in the call `speler1gooien()` because it's causing your function to be executed immediately, and the return value is being passed as the click event handler.

```
buttonSpeler1.addEventListener("click", speler1gooien);
//                                                   ^ removed ()
```

By removing the parenthesis, you are passing the function object, instead of executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to attach function speler1gooien as onclick handler, but your code attaches as handler the result of spele1gooien function. Just remove `()` following name of that function

```
window.onload = function () {
        buttonSpeler1 = document.getElementById("buttonspeler1");
        buttonSpeler2 = document.getElementById("buttonspeler2");
        tafelp2.src = "images/rechts_" + aantalBekersP2 + ".png";
        resultaat = document.getElementById("resultaat");
        buttonSpeler1.addEventListener("click", speler1gooien);
};

var speler1gooien =  function() {
   // some code
}
```